# Customize startup screen text

Tags: start-up

I want to add a string to the startup screen. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495435/how-do-i-customize-the-welcome-screen-in-emacs) and customized the `fancy-startup-text` variable, like this

```
  (add-to-list 'fancy-startup-text '("\nYou are running a customized Emacs configuration. See "  :link
    ("here"
     #[257 "\300\301!\207"
           [browse-url-default-browser "http://github.com/izahn/dotemacs/"]
           3 "\n\n(fn BUTTON)"]
     "Open the README file")
    "\nfor information about these customizations.\n"))
```

That worked on my desktop computer, but when I tried on my laptop (with a small screen) I find a different startup screen, without the Emacs logo at the top, and without my additional string. I found a discussion on the emacs mailing list discussing how different startup screens are shown depending on the size of the initial frame (unfortunately I cannot locate this now), so I think this is expected. But what I cannot figure out is how to customize the text for the simple startup screen (without the logo) that is shown when the initial frame is small. I tried customizing `fancy-about-text`, i.e.

```
 (add-to-list 'fancy-about-text '("\nYou are running a customized Emacs configuration. See "  :link
    ("here"
     #[257 "\300\301!\207"
           [browse-url-default-browser "http://github.com/izahn/dotemacs/"]
           3 "\n\n(fn BUTTON)"]
     "Open the README file")
    "\nfor information about these customizations.\n"))
```

but that did not work.

Comment: While not an exact answer to your question, this Q&A uses a custom scratch buffer which I use instead of a startup screen: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38709/2418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is any variable you can set to insert text into the text-only startup screen that is displayed when Emacs starts with a small initial frame. It looks like `fancy-startup-screen` gets called if the display is big enough, otherwise `normal-splash-screen` is called. Unlike `fancy-startup-screen` the contents that get inserted into the buffer by `normal-splash-screen` are all hard coded into the function.

For now I've set Emacs to startup in full screen, so the fancy startup screen is used. An alternative would be to set `inhibit-startup-screen` and the add `fancy-startup-screen` to the `emacs-startup-hook`.

**Update:** I'm now using the following hack to always use `fancy-startup-screen`, even on small displays:

```
(defun always-use-fancy-splash-screens-p () 1)
  (defalias 'use-fancy-splash-screens-p 'always-use-fancy-splash-screens-p)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do something similar to what Ista originally asked about, but different enough that the method described would not work for me.

I wanted to insert information into the `*GNU Emacs*` splash buffer after the Emacs version and copyright lines. Adding to a list like `fancy-about-text` would not accomplish this since the Emacs version info and copyright lines are not in a list, but are hard coded into the `fancy-startup-tail` function. Unfortunately there is no hook that is run following the execution of the `fancy-startup-tail` function. I wrote a function that did what I wanted without hard coding anything that was to be inserted into it. I used the Elisp function `advice-add` to add my function as an advice to the `fancy-startup-tail` function to be run after it had completed execution.
I believe that this approach would also answer Ista's desire to modify the normal splash screen.

Answer (score 1):

To make arbitrary changes to the main text of the fancy splash screen:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `fancy-startup-text` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- Copy the definition of `fancy-startup-text` (<kbd>M-h</kbd><kbd>M-w</kbd> ought to do it).
- Paste this into your init file.
- Make whatever changes you want.  E.g.:

```el
(defconst fancy-startup-text
  `((:face (variable-pitch font-lock-comment-face)
     "Welcome to "
     :link ("THIS FILE"
            ,(lambda (_button)
               (find-file "~/.emacs.d/init.el"))
            "Your init.el file")
     ", and also "
     :link ("GNU Emacs"
[...]
```

n.b. The `fancy-about-text` definition which follows is for the "Help -> About Emacs" screen.

There's obviously a structure to it, but it should be simple enough to follow.  It's largely a concatenation of strings (like "Welcome to ") which are inserted verbatim, and links which mostly have the structure:

```el
:link ("LINK TEXT" ,(lambda (_button) DO-A-THING) "HOVER TEXT")
```

Where `DO-A-THING` is any arbitrary Emacs Lisp, which will be `(find-file "/path/to/file")` for visiting a file.

`(lambda (_button) ...)` is an anonymous function definition (which expects to be passed a button argument that it doesn't care about); and the preceding comma `,` is there to *evaluate* the function definition (because this entire `fancy-startup-text` structure is backquoted with `` ` ``).  Clicking the link text then calls the function which does the thing.