# How to very slightly edit the welcome splash to have a list of files to open in new tabs?

Tags: customize, customization, custom

New to emacs, and I want to keep the welcome splash, but with links to a few files to open in a new tab when I click on them. These would include a file for notes I'm making when going through emacs tutorials and such, a daily planner file, and a fun writing project I'm working on. My plan is basically to "live in" emacs for as much of my computer time as I can, and that, on top of some stuff like Rainer's org-mode tutorial, that'll be enough to get me familiar with emacs.

Comment: I suggest that this question be closed.  I've moved the answer I wrote for this to that duplicate question, and you can read it here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/80608/454 (and be sure to read the other answers as well, which cover situations in which a different, more compact splash screen might be used).